# Axon Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Unit of Work already has an Aggregate with the same identifier

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

I have a report runner aggregate which is handling Report Run Command. The aggregate has a target identifier and both the commands have the same target identifier.

Getting the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Unit of Work already has an Aggregate with the same identifier
>       at org.axonframework.common.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:54) ~[axon-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
>       at org.axonframework.commandhandling.model.AbstractRepository.newInstance(AbstractRepository.java:84) ~[axon-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
>       at org.axonframework.commandhandling.AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler$AggregateConstructorCommandHandler.handle(AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler.java:181) ~[axon-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
>       at org.axonframework.commandhandling.AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler$AggregateConstructorCommandHandler.handle(AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler.java:170) ~[axon-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
>       at org.axonframework.commandhandling.AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler.handle(AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler.java:148) ~[axon-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
>       at org.axonframework.commandhandling.AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler.handle(AggregateAnnotationCommandHandler.java:40) ~[axon-core-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]

Something like

```
public class ExecuteReportsAggregate
{
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String reportId; 

    // Command Handler and Even Source Handlers
}
```

Execute Report Command

```
@Value
public class ExecuteReportCommand
{
    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    String reportId;
}
```

Report Executed Command

```
@Value
public class ReportExecutedCommand
{
    // @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private String reportId;
}
```

Spring boot looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ConfigurableApplicationContext config = SpringApplication.run(SsmpPreopenCommand.class, args);
    CommandBus commandBus = config.getBean(CommandBus.class);

    commandBus.dispatch(GenericCommandMessage.asCommandMessage(new ExecuteReportCommand("12345",
        "asdfasdf Errors", "/home/teo", new ServiceCredentials())));

    // commandBus.dispatch(GenericCommandMessage.asCommandMessage(new
    // ReportExecutedCommand("12345")));
}
```

Comment: I think you would have to provide the code for the relevant `@CommandHandlers` and `@EventSourcingHandlers` for us to say something sensible about this.

Comment: Can you move CommandHandlers to separate class

Answer (score 2):

Axon is handling the instances of Aggregates you implement. Therefor you mark the relevant methods of Aggregate by marking it with the `@CommandHandler` annotation.

(Usually) an aggregate should have a:

- no-args constructor
- a constructor having a command as a first argument, marked by `@CommandHandler` annotation
- at least one method marked with `@EventSourcingHandler` annotation, accepting as a first parameter an event fired by the execution of this constructor which is performed by `AggregateLifecycle#apply()` method and setting the field marked by the `AggregateIdentifier`.
- any number of further methods accepting a command as a first parameter marked with `@CommandHandler` annotation
- any number of further methods accepting a event as a first parameter marked with `@EventSourcingHandler` annotation

If you send the first command on the `CommandBus`, Axon will try to find the Aggegate with the matching identifier and, since it does not exists yet create it by calling the constructor and passing the command to it. The constructor will call the `AggregateLifecycle#apply()` method and fire the event (stored by Axon), so from this point of time on, Axon will try to send *ALL* commands with the same `TargetAggregateIdentifier`to this aggregate instance.

If you try to create (and store) another Aggregate instance of the SAME type with the SAME aggregate identifier, you will fail and see the exception above.

To avoid, you want to use 'create-on-check-fail' pattern. See my [thoughts on it here...](https://zambrovski.gitbooks.io/software-architecture/content/CQRS/putting-your-code-into-the-right-place.html)

Kind regards,

Simon